# last day/time of month

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I get the last day of the month to be 11:59:59 pm? Right now it is showing 05/31/2019 12:00 AM. If I just do sysdate it just shows the time I ran it. Thanks.

```
LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'))
```

Comment: If this is for a range selecting all `date`s in (or to till the end of) a month use a left open interval using the first day of the *next* month.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding one day to the last day of the current month, then subtracting one minute:

```
SELECT
    LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')) + INTERVAL '1' DAY - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
FROM dual;
```

Or, if you want to also see the time component, use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in place of `SYSDATE`:

```
SELECT
    LAST_DAY(TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'MM')) + INTERVAL '1' DAY - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
FROM dual;
```

This outputted:

```
30.06.2019 23:59:59
```

Comment: Why not `+ INTERVAL '11:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND`?

Comment: @mathguy Why not indeed.  You seem to know all the tricks in Oracle :-)

Answer (score 0):

The *oldfashioned* way would be to subtract a second (that's what `1 / (24*60*60)` represents as there are 24 hours in a day, 60 minutes in an hour and 60 seconds in a minute) from the first day of the next month (and that's what `trunc(add_months(sysdate, 1))` does):

```
SQL> select sysdate today,
  2         trunc(add_months(sysdate, 1)) - 1/(24*60*60) result
  3  from dual;

TODAY                  RESULT
---------------------- ----------------------
06/01/2019 07:52:40 AM 06/30/2019 11:59:59 PM

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') + INTERVAL '1' MONTH - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
FROM dual;
```

(This has one less step than Tim's solution.)

Or in the older-fashioned method:

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1) - 1/(24*60*60)
```

If you convert this to a timestamp, you will see the time value:

```
SELECT CAST(TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM') + INTERVAL '1' MONTH - INTERVAL '1' SECOND as TIMESTAMP)
FROM dual;
```